# how to Check if the htmlelement is exist in webpage

Tags: vb.net, webbrowser-control

how to stop the timer if the specified html element was not present in the webpage

```
Try
            If WebBrowser1.ReadyState = WebBrowserReadyState.Complete Then

            Dim Page As HtmlElementCollection = WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("a")
            For Each Element As HtmlElement In Page
                If Element.GetAttribute("href").Contains("/email") Then
                    id = Element.GetAttribute("href").ToString()
                    If Not ListBox1.Items.Contains(id) Then
                        ListBox1.Items.Add(id)
                    End If
                End If
            Next

        End If
            catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error scraping", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
    End Try
```

in the above code the link which contain "email" is listed is listbox how to alert or stop the timer if the link contain "email" is not present